# Position a flexbox item's child at the bottom of its container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`flex-item`'s are positioned horizontally along the flex line.

I want each `flex-item` to be the same height while positioning their `flex-item-three` to the bottom - with `flex-item-one` at the top and `flex-item-two` directly below it.

```
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
    <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
    <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>

#flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flex `auto` margin on `flex-item-2` or `flex-item-3` will do the job.

```
.flex-item-two {
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```css
.flex-item-two {
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.flex-item-one { background-color: chartreuse; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
.flex-item-two { background-color: goldenrod; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
.flex-item-three { background-color: rebeccapurple; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
.flex-item-three {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```css
.flex-item-three {
    margin-top: auto;
}
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.flex-item-one { background-color: chartreuse; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
.flex-item-two { background-color: goldenrod; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
.flex-item-three { background-color: rebeccapurple; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-one"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-two"></div>
        <div class="flex-item-three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More details here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: In your 2nd example it seems I was missing, critically, flex-item style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;". flex-item-three style="margin-top: auto;" alone won't do it. Thanks - nice docs!